# series with irrational numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity, irrational-numbers

Yeah the title says everything I will explain this quick if someone is so smart and nice than he has my ammiration! Here you are :: if we take an irrational number like π or e or whatever and we write this π+π-π… (ecc) at infinity of this series what could possibly come out?? I hope somebody can explain this thanks in advance to everybody!!

Comment: That series does not converge, at least in the usual sense of convergence. So nothing comes out... what would you have expected?

Comment: @Lovsovs No, not even $\infty$. It does not diverge to $\infty$, *it does not converge* (even in $[-\infty,\infty]$).

Comment: @ClementC. Whoops, read it as $\pi+\pi+\pi+\dots$. I will blame it on the lack of MathJax :)

Comment: So if I understand right this is like a superior order series?? Like a metaseries or something like that?

Comment: No, it is just a divergent series. Not everything is convergent. (Also, this has nothing to do with $\pi$ being irrational. Replace it by $1$, or your favorite non-zero number, it'll be the same).

Comment: The title does _not_ say everything; there are plenty of series with irrational numbers that are completely unlike the ones you're interested in. As it turns out, you get the same answer whether the first term is rational or irrational, so half the title isn't even important.

Comment: Does somebody thinks in a upper degree level or simply with some ordinal trick this can be done?? I know for certain for example that infinity has replicable properties at the logical level and math is not systematically complete in a lot of fields of research so if we take like some sectors of n exp something (infinitely speaking) maybe it's like this (thanks to everybody in any case!) Sorry for not using your preferred formatting but when I think I'm quite chaotic and quick XD (sometimes they just make me go to take the holy water...)

Comment: @user363984 Kindda, you can see details in the wikipedia link in my answer

Comment: It seems that you are a little kid who has been reading a lot of adult stuff on the Internet lately

Comment: I may be childish I don't negate that but I am twenty lol!

Answer (score 2):

This series is analagous to $1-1+1-1+ \cdots = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n$. This is not a convergent series, because the sequence of martial sums does not converge, it just keeps alternating between $0$ and $1$.

$S_1 = 1$

$S_2 = 1-1=0$

$S_3 = 1-1+1=1$

$\vdots$

**EDIT:** Thanks to Clement C.

If you allow yourself weaker notions of convergence (which you usually study in upper division classes) you can assign a value to some divergent series.

[Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Properties_of_summation_methods)

Comment: You can also assign other values, depending on what "convergence" you consider. But *this is not in the same sense* -- *your answer is very misleading, IMO*. Whatever class you take, the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n$ is not defined -- usually, another notation is used to specify what convergence type is used.

Comment: @ClementC. Sorry, I haven't taken those high level courses myself yet, it's just what I've been told. I edited the answer, is it better now?

Comment: I guess I'd add "considering alternative (weaker) notions of convergence" at the end, with maybe a link to [this section on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Properties_of_summation_methods).

Comment: @ClementC. Ok done, thanks!

Comment: I think just now of it now I will say something interesting maybe some sort of sinusoidal waveform can come out of this sin(x) is similar to this so what I said is just the repeating "samples" of the signal (if interpolated in time) so this lacks the time value to be understood hehhe!! That's why usually these things in static math don't make sense so series are just like sliding values on a graph!! Not bad eh?

Comment: If we think series like dynamical domains it's pretty easy after all why did I not thought about this before??

Comment: OK, now it is obvious that the OP is a troll

Comment: Why you think I'm a troll the introduction section points out to be open minded so what am I saying wrong?? I mean no offense to anybody! And I already thanked everybody in advance so what's the problem?

Comment: I admit too I "speak strange" but math itself is quirky I don't see the problem...

Answer (score 2):

So what you are looking for is a series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{a_n} x$$

where $a_n$ is a sequence of natural numbers and $x$ is an irrational number.

This series always fails the limit test, so it is divergent